# C Starting daemon as external programm?

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec

I have a C Linux programm which uses `fork()` to run as a daemon and (once daemon runs fine) ends itself.

Now I would like to do the same for an external program.

This should be the workflow:

1. start launcher program
2. launch internal daemon
3. start external program which itself will use `fork()` and run as daemon
4. exit launcher program

The internal daemon should be able to monitor the external daemon and check if it is up and running if possible. No direct communication between these two should appear (they will communicate through MQTT).

Parts 1. and 2. are fine so far. Now I read about `exec()` to start external programs but in this case the caller would never return as is waiting for the called program to exit.

Am I right about the following for 3.?
Do exec() and start the program. The program itself will do a `fork()` and run in background, parent process will exit and thus the launcher program will exit, too. But isn't the exit of the called program treated as an error for `exec()`?

Thanks a lot!

/KNEBB

Comment: Yes, for step 3, `exec()` would only return control to the original program if it failed to load the executable program. On success, the external program will have taken over the current process and never returns to the original program, so there would be no step 4.

Comment: An alternative approach for step 3 would be for the original program to fork again, with its child executing the external program (which no longer needs to fork). The parent can then exit at step 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible approaches.

First approach:

```
1. Start launcher
     |
2. fork() --(child)--> Internal daemon process.
     |(parent)
3. exec()
   External program (replacing launcher)
     |
   fork() --(child)--> External daemon process.
     |(parent)
4. exit()
```

Second approach:

```
1. Start launcher
     |
2. fork() --(child)--> Internal daemon process.
     |(parent)
3. fork() ---------->(child)
     |(parent)         |
     |               exec()
     |               External main (background) process
4. exit()
```

The difference between the approaches is where the second fork occurs.  In the first approach, the launcher and the external program both fork child processes and their parents exit. In the second approach, the launcher forks two child processes and the external program does not fork. In both approaches, two child daemon processes are left behind and their parents have exited, so they both get re-parented to the `init` process (PID 1).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So in case I prefer not to re-parent the external I could do a fork within the internal daemon doing an exec(). So we have the internal daemon and a child of it being replaced by the exec() external daemon. 
So I will be (hmmm...how?) able to monitor if the external daemon is running finde, right?

Comment: Yes, somehow (via some interprocess control mechanism or a pipe) the internal daemon needs to told the PID of the external daemon. Once it knows the PID, it can use the `kill` system call with signal 0 to check its existence.

Comment: Ah! Great hint about using kill(). This is perfect now!
I am going to figure out how I might send the pid- I guess as they will anyways communicate through mqtt I will use this, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Start launcher
     |
2. fork() ------  (child)
     |(launcher)    |
3.  exit()        fork() -->internal daemon
                    |(child) 
4.                exec() ---> external program
                                  |
                               fork() ----------- external daemon 
                                  |
                               exit()
```

Well, thinking twice about this I think your suggestion is the better one. In both cases the daemon processes get re-parented anyways, right?
Any in neither case I can really monitor the other daemon, correct?

Thanks again!